Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost:2660/CoreService/202101/netTcp. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:02. TCP code 10061
We have been encountering the following error frequently:
Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost:2660/CoreService/202101/netTcp. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:02. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:2660.

Performing an IIS Reset resolves the issue temporarily.
Based on the information from the following link, We already disabled the Core.Communicator.
Additionally, we have verified link for the binding configurations and ensured that the 202101 related configurations are correctly placed in web.config, webroot/web.config, and TcmServiceHost.exe.config.
The Tridion Content Manager Service Host is also running when the error occurs.
Assumption: If someone is using a CMS from the Office network, and due to network blockers, a specific port is disabled, will this affect only the user? Will it forcefully terminate the connection with the CMS server in this scenario? Are there any other potential implications?
Please provide your guidance on how to permanently resolve this issue.

Do you get different results depending on where you connect from? This is worth submitting a ticket on RWS Gateway.

Are you trying to access coreservice outside the CM server?

Such errors imply that the Tridion CM Service Host Windows Service (TcmServiceHost.exe) is not up-and-running at that moment. Maybe it goes down / crashes sometimes?  Please check the Windows Application and System Event Logs for signs of this service crashing / restarting.
